# delete tag content xml with notepad ++

Tags: xml, replace, tags, notepad++

Wonder if anybody is having knowlege about removing from-to content from xml files?
 Have a lot of xml files that contains data that i wants to delete.
Im trying to use notepad ++ that have the replace function.
Can i somehowe use notepad ++ to select area that start with tag example:

```
<greetingCard:state generatedStep="THEME_SELECTION" to the area that ends with tag :

    </greetingCard:greetingCard>
```

I have several xml with a lots of tags, but wants to delete the content from the
 tag. Is this possible some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex function, but i don't have use notepad++ currently... If you use SublimeText or regex function if exist in notepad++, create similar regex :

```
<greetingCard:state generatedStep="THEME_SELECTION"(.*)<\/greetingCard:greetingCard>
```